# Are muxes more "expensive" than other logic?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, synthesis

This is mostly out of curiosity.

One fragment from some VHDL code that I've been working on recently resembles the following:

```
led_q <= (pwm_d and ch_ena) when pwm_ena = '1' else ch_ena;
```

This is a mux-style expression, of course.  But it's also equivalent to the following basic logic expression (at least when ignoring non-binary states):

```
led_q <= ch_ena and (pwm_d or not pwm_ena);
```

Is one "better" than the other in terms of logic utilisation or efficiency when actually implemented in an FPGA?  Is it preferable to use one over the other, or is the compiler smart enough to pick the "best" on its own?

(For the curious, the purpose of the expression is to define the state of an LED -- if `ch_ena` is false it should always be off as the channel is disabled, otherwise it should either be on solidly or flashing according to `pwm_d`, according to `pwm_ena` (PWM enable).  I think the first form describes this more obviously than the second, although it's not too hard to realise how the second behaves.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a simple logical expression, like the one shown, where the synthesis tool can easily create a complete truth table, the expression is likely to be converted to an internal truth table, which is then directly mapped to the available FPGA LUT resources.  Since the truth table is identical for the two equivalent expressions, the hardware will also be the same.

However, for complex expressions where a complete truth table can't be generated, e.g. when using arithmetic operations, and/or where dedicated resources are available, the synthesis tool may choose to hold an internal representation that is more closely related to the original VHDL code, and in this case the VHDL coding style can have a great impact on the resulting logic, even for equivalent expressions.

In the end, the implementation is tool specific, so the best way to find out what logic is generated is to try it with the specific tool, in special for large or timing critical parts of the design, where the implementation is critical.

Answer (score 1):

In general it depends on the target architecture. For Xilinx FPGAs the logic is mostly mapped into LUTs with sporadic use of the hard logic resources where the mapper can make use of them. Every possible LUT configuration has essentially equal performance so there's little benefit to scrutinizing the mapper's work unless you're really pushing the speed limits of the device where you'd be forced into manually instantiating hand-mapped LUTs.

Non-LUT based architectures like the Actel/Microsemi device families use 2-input muxes as the main logic primitive and everything is mapped down to them. You can't generalize what is best across all types of FPGAs and CPLDs but nowadays you can mostly trust that the mapper will do a decent enough job using timing constraints to push it toward the results you need.

With regards to the question I think it is best to avoid obscure Boolean expressions where possible. They tend to be hard to decipher months later when you forgot what you meant them to do. I would lean toward the `when-else` simply from a code maintenance point of view. Even for this trivial example you have to think closely about what behavior it describes whereas the `when-else` describes the intended behavior directly in human level syntax.

HDLs work best when you use the highest abstraction possible and avoid wallowing around with low-level bit twiddling. This is a place where VHDL truly shines if you leverage the more advanced features of the language and move away from describing raw logic everywhere. Let the synthesizer do the work. Introductory learning materials focus on the low level structural gate descriptions and logic expressions because that is easiest for beginners to get a start on but it is *not* the best way to use VHDL for complex designs in the long run.

Of course there are situations where Booleans are better, particularly when doing bitwise operations across vectors in parallel which requires messy loops to do the same imperatively. It all depends on the context.

Comment: I tend to disagree.
I have had many experiences where the Synthesis tool has done a absolutely horrible job optimizing high level VHDL compared to the lower level equivalent.

The tricky thing here is that you never really know if the Synthesis tool has done a good job or not.
Also, tiny changes in how high-level HDL is written can have a big impact on the Synthesis result.
These uncertainties are avoided if you use a HDL style where you as the DHL developer can easily see what the digital equivalent to the code should be.